# Haskell Instance wrapping []

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create an instance of a type that wraps []; i.e.,

```
instance Foo (NonNull []) where
```

(where NonNull is Michael Snoyman's [Data.NonNull](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.13.0/docs/Data-NonNull.html))
This works fine for, say,

```
instance Foo [] where
```

But with `NonNull []`, I get

```
Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘NonNull []’ has kind ‘*’
```

I have tried using RankNTypes to provide an explicit forall:

```
instance ∀ α . Foo (NonNull [α]) where
```

With a similar result:

```
Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘NonNull [α]’ has kind ‘*’
```

And also a type synonym:

```
type NonNullList α = NonNull [α]
instance ToSeq NonNullList where
```

which gives:

```
The type synonym ‘NonNullList’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
```

I'm sure this must be possible, but I am missing the incantation.
Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 4):

Your last attempt is the closest one, but you need a `newtype` instead of a `type` synonym (`data` would work too):

```
newtype NonNullList α = NonNullList (NonNull [α])

instance ToSeq NonNullList where ...
```

`NonNull []` which you tried first doesn't make sense because `NonNull`'s argument must be a type (like `[Int]`), not a type constructor like `[]`. You should see a second error, like [in this similar example](https://repl.it/repls/LawfulSevereShoutcast):

```
instance Functor (Maybe []) where

main.hs:5:19: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Maybe []’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘(Maybe [])’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Maybe [])’
  |
5 | instance Functor (Maybe []) where
  |                   ^^^^^^^^
main.hs:5:25: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘[]’
      Expected a type, but ‘[]’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the first argument of ‘Maybe’, namely ‘[]’
      In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘(Maybe [])’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Maybe [])’
  |
5 | instance Functor (Maybe []) where
  |                         ^^
```

Comment: Right, thank you - but the newtype means that I can't use it for its original intent, an instance of `Foo` for (`NonNull [a]`) (for all a).  Given that the kind of NonNull * -> *, and the kind of [] is * -> *; surely the kind of NonNull [] is *->*, which is the same as []; hence, I would hope to be able to express this.

Comment: You are missing escapes, so I am not sure what you expect the kind of `NonNull` to be. But in fact it is `* -> *`, so `NonNull []` doesn't kind-check.

Comment: You are right, I mean `* -> *`; and `[]` is also `* -> *`, so I expect the kind of `NonNull []` to be `* -> *`, which is the same as `[]`; which does kind-check.  To be clear, I am sure that you are correct, I am trying to understand why my reasoning fails.

Comment: `NonNull :: * -> *` means its argument can only be `*`, not `* -> *`. It works for kinds just like for types; if you have `not :: Bool -> Bool`, `not not` doesn't typecheck.